# Get request count from Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

Is there any way to get statistics such as service / endpoint access for services defined in Kubernetes cluster?

I've read about Heapster, but it doesn't seem to provide these statistics.  Plus, the whole setup is tremendously complicated and relies on a ton of third-party components.  I'd really like something much, much simpler than that.

I've been looking into what may be available in `kube-system` namespace, and there's a bunch of containers and services, there, Heapster including, but they are effectively inaccessible because they require authentication I cannot provide, and `kubectl` doesn't seem to have any API to access them (or does it?).

Answer (score 1):

Heapster is the agent that collects data, but then you need a monitoring agent to interpret these data. On GCP, for example, that's fluentd who gets these metrics and sends to Stackdriver.

[Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) is an excellent monitoring tool. I would recommend this one, if youare not on GCP.

If you would be on GCP, then as mentioned above you have Stackdriver Monitoring, that is configured by default for K8s clusters. All you have to do is to create a Stackdriver accound (this is done by one click from GCP Console), and you are good to go.

Comment: No, that's not even close. Sorry. I don't need third-party monitoring tools. I want to know where can I put my code to count the property that interests me.

Comment: I think you are not realizing the difficulty of what you want to do. All I can say is good luck.